# How to implement customizeable rules for time table scheduling?

Tags: database, algorithm, database-design, scheduled-tasks, computer-science

I'm working on implementation of the library that serves one single purpose: making flexible scheduling for repeating events.

For example, one user wants to schedule a Notification to be sent "on Tuesday at 7 PM every even week of October in leap year". Another one wants it to be sent "on 13-th day every odd month at 6 AM" or "at 7 AM every Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday".

My question is very general, or abstract, and probably relates to some field of discreet math / computer science. Can we express schedules from example above using simple arithmetic over integer timestamps? What operations are enough to create a flexible language powerful enough to express almost any recurring events?

Comment: `Can we express schedules from example above using simple arithmetic over integer timestamps?` Can you add some demonstration examples of this. I can take a guess, but that just leads to a discussion instead of getting to an answer.

Comment: `What operations are enough to create a flexible language powerful enough to express almost any recurring events?` I hate to say, but that is subjective. If this were to be a real world system, I assure you no matter how much thought you put into your design, a user some where will come up with a scenario that you did not consider and is most likely valid.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you will need to support the calculation of simple boolean expressions - those which use a predefined list of predicates (e.g. `isLeapYear`, `isMonday`, `isEvenWeek`, etc.) combining them with the logical operators AND, OR, NOT (and allow for braces to change the precedence). Once you have a piece of code which is able to calculate boolean expressions - the rest is just to define a suitable amount of predicates.

The predicates may have argument(s) - e.g. `isDayOfMonth(x)` or `isHour(14)`.

In the database you will most probably store the AST (abstract syntax tree) of the expression - but it is also possible to store the expression as string, purely your choice.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I believe this model could work, and storing AST is bright idea! I thought, may be exist some book, reference, publication related to programming and Grigorian calendar system used by you, earthlings :)